# Proxy server with Express on Node.js is wrapping callback multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, proxy

### Problem

I'm writing a pretty simple proxy server in node. It takes a requests, passes it on, then collects the response, and sends it back the original caller. Main purpose of the proxy is to wrap the response to the original caller with a callback. problem I'm having, is that the `response.on('data', function...` gets called multiple times for large responses, and the callback gets wrapped each time (only want it to be wrapped once around the entire response)

### Code

```
function respond(response) {
res.statusCode = response.statusCode;
// when the server sends a data

response.on('data', function(chunk) {
  var chunkString = '';
  // wrap chunck in callback
  if (jsonpCallback !== '') {
    chunkString += jsonpCallback;
    chunkString +=  '(';
    chunkString += chunk.toString();
    chunkString += ')';

    res.write(chunkString);

  } else {
    chunkString += chunk.toString('utf8');
    res.write(chunkString);
  }
});

response.on('end', function() {
  res.end();
});
}
```

### What I've Tried

I attempted to solve the issue by adding a counter variable. I then only attached the callback when the `counter === 0`. However, since I don't know how many times it may get called, I don't know when to wrap the last `)` of the callback.

Comment: Why don't you store the payload received at response.on('data') and only wraps and send the whole content once after you receive the response.on('end') event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution would be something like this:

```
function respond(response) { 
    var payload = "";
    res.statusCode = response.statusCode; // when the server sends a data 

    response.on('data', function(chunk) { 
        payload += chunk;
    }); 

    response.on('end', function() { 
        if (jsonpCallback !== "") { 
            res.write(jsonpCallback + "(" + payload + ")");
        } else { 
            res.write(payload.toString('utf8'));
        }
        res.end(); 
   }); 
}
```

This way you first collect all the data from the original response, and only when it is finished, you send it out to the original requester.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable-flag that says whether you need to send a closing bracket:

```
function respond(response) {
    res.statusCode = response.statusCode;
    var needClose = false;

    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      if (jsonpCallback !== '' && !needClose) {
          res.write( jsonpCallback );
          res.write( '(' );
          needClose = true;
      }
      res.write(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
       if (needClose) res.write( ')' );
       res.end();
    });
}
```